# Windows Mobile: what is the difference between warm-reset and cold-reset?

Tags: boot, windows-mobile, reset

Windows Mobile: what is the difference between warm-reset, cold-reset, and clean-boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Warm reset is essentially the same as rebooting your computer; the OS is restarted, along with any startup programs, and your data is not affected.

Cold reset/boot is like doing a reformat of your hard drive and restoring it back to just what was on the device when it was new from the factory. Cold will wipe out any programs you may have installed and any data you have on the device's internal memory.